# Eclipse - duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

All:

I have a main project and a static library project in an Eclipse workspace.  I finally got the two projects compiling and running without errors.  Now, I've added a few CMake files to build all projects using CMake and I am getting the following duplicate symbols errors:

[image: Console image]

[image: Problem image]

Do any of these errors make any sense to anybody?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are linking with cmake itself. Did you copy cmake source files into the projects?

Comment: Did you build CMake from sources?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very obscure from your question. One solution is that you may have include file in the header .cpp instead of .h file. If so, please replace cpp with h and the problem will be solved.